# Testing Cordova apps and bluetooth

Tags: automated-testing

What is the best way to test cordova application which uses bluetooth to talk with custom hardware? Do I need to sniff traffic to make sure they are working well or?

Comment: What *specifically* do you need to test? The interface to the custom hardware? The display of the custom hardware's responses? Whether the custom hardware receives responses you send? Do you need to automate testing the full loop in a single test set (I hope not), or can you automate the different pieces and run a few manual tests to cover the interconnections? Please update your question with more information.

Comment: I need to automate test for mobile apps functionality which also includes bluetooth communication testing.

Comment: "mobile apps functionality" - what sort of 'functionality' are we talking about?  Again, be more specific.  Tell us the actual scenatio, not generalities please.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the simplest route; do input-output testing. Perform some action and verify the result. If the communication fails, so does your test as the expected result/response will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose not, but why do you ask us ? ask your clients- developers, marketing, sales, management and customers.

Is the custom app part of your responsibility ? if not, than you can **probably** assume that bluetooth is working, but what if you are using Cordova wrong, or your hardware is not well supported causing you to work in lower performance or reliability ? imagine everything is working as planned, but when you sniff it you see that each message is sent twice (been there, seen that...)